# AS3 SharedObject, unique var?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm playing around in AS3 and trying to make a easy note application.

So I thought that I would store the notes with `SharedObject` so is it possible to somehow say `so.data.myVariable` and get/create that shared object dynamically?

I've googled but don't find anything?

EDIT: My solution!

I managed to fix it after many hours of thinking!

In Main.as when creating the Object.

```
addChild(Obj)
Obj.setUniqueID(SomeID);
```

In my class that would contain the sharedObject. (Object.as)

```
public function setUniqueID(uniqueID:String):void
{
   soData = SharedObject.getLocal(uniqueID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible actually SharedObject.data is object that dynamic class so we can create property.Please follow bellow code.

```
public var sharedObj:SharedObject;

        private function initSharedObject():void{
            sharedObj = SharedObject.getLocal("myNotes");
        }

        private function clearAllNotes():void 
        {
            sharedObj.clear();
        }

        private function saveNote(variableName:String,valueToSave:*/* need to specify your type */):void
        {
            sharedObj.data[variableName] = valueToSave;
            sharedObj.flush();
        }

        private function getNote(variableName:String):* /* need to specify your type */
        {
            return sharedObj.data[variableName];
        }
```

More details http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects
              http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=lsos_2.html

Comment: Managed to fix it, look at my post. I've edited it! Thanks anyway!